# TL494 with synchronized output rectifiers for push-pull converter

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I want to build a push-pull converter with synchronized output MOSFETs using a [TL494](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl494) IC which has two outputs that can directly drive only two transistors.

The output of the push-pull converter is 12 V, 30 A from an input of 36 V to 86 V with a switching frequency of 30 kHz.

I have done a small simulation in LTspice in which I used gate drive transformers to drive all four MOSFETs. I utilized an NPN transitor's collector to provide an overlap for the output MOSFETs which is required for the push-pull converter. I have attached the schematic I simulated below.

The simulation I have done is only to show me the waveforms of the driver voltages and currents.

[image]

Can such a configuration work, and is the overlap enough to ensure good performance?

Below are the waveforms of the gate voltages of the output MOSFETs i.e M3 and M4:

[image]

I am also getting a slight distortion for the above waveforms where the voltage falls from 15 V to about 11 V seeing that the Vcc is 15 V. How can I avoid this?

For the circuit that is driving the primary side MOSFETs i.e. M1 and M2 I am getting a slight distortion of about 1 V but the waveform seems to be good. How can I avoid this distortion? Below are the waveforms of the primary side MOSFETs' gate voltages:

[image]

Please help me debug it and offer me any guidance on how to approach the design.

Comment: _”overlap for the output MOSFETs which is required for the push-pull converter”_ Opposite, you need a deadband. Not as critical as for a half-bridge as current will be limited by the transformer inductance but having both switches on will not do you anything good.

Comment: General schematic tip: draw your positive voltages pointing up and ground/negative voltages pointing down. Several things are currently upside down in your schematic.

Comment: That configuration cannot work because (in your own words) *The simulation I have done is only to show me the waveforms of the driver voltages and currents* <-- there appears to be nothing sensible connected the the MOSFETs that could be used to determine if the configuration works. Short story --> where does the output load connect? I didn't see any values for k either.

Comment: @winny the overlap is not a must?

Comment: @Andy aka let me draw the full schematic then edit my question

Comment: Opposite! Avoid any overlap.

Comment: @winny noted. Just for better understanding, from a book I use for power electronics 'Pulse-width Modulated DC–DC Power Converters by MARIAN K. KAZIMIERCZUK' there are 4 time intervals, when a transistor and an output diode are conducting and when both output diodes are conducting at the same time. Kindly explain yourself further or provide me with a reference text

Comment: Sorry, no references. Just simulate it with and without overlap and form your own understanding.

Comment: @winny The full schematic is yet to be seen of course, but if it's the usual approach, it will be primary hard switching and secondary current-sourcing i.e. a choke-input rectifier with synchronous switching. The rectifiers therefore are best with overlap, because a current-sourcing inverter is inverse of a voltage-sourcing inverter.

Comment: ...In CCM, I should add; duty drops again in DCM. So it's not a great solution to hard wire it this way over the whole operating range.

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh, are we talking about the control for the rectifiers and not the primary switches? I can’t tell from the schematic.